# Статусы у дубликатов?

Tags: обсуждение, мета, дубликаты, метка-модератора

Надо ли ставить статусную метку (например, [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be)) на вопросе, который закрыт как дубликат, или достаточно на основном вопросе?

Понятно, что специально выискивать все дубликаты, чтобы поставить на них метку, никто не будет, но интересуют следующие аспекты:

- Имеет ли для участников какую-либо ценность эта метка на закрытых как дубликаты вопросах? Важно ли при этом, насколько одинаковыми являются вопросы? Например, если они полные дубликаты, или если закрытый - более частный?
- Стали бы вы помечать дубликат тревогой для добавления подобной метки и почему?

PS: Это обсуждение, а не справка, так что предлагаем варианты.

Comment: *"что специально выискивать все дубликаты, чтобы поставить на них метку, никто не будет"* - есть у нас тут один товарищ, как раз по этому делу ..

Comment: @Kromster призвать к ответу!

Answer (score 2):

Моё мнение:

- Если тревога стоит, то добавить метку мне не лень.
- Если более конкретный вопрос закрыт как дубликат вопроса с большим списком багов, то метка имеет ценность, поскольку показывает, что конкретный случай исправлен, тогда как статус других багов может быть другим.

По остальным вопросам пока не определился.

Answer (score 2):

Можно наткнуться как на дубликат, так и на оригинал. Если вешать [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) только на оригинал, то человеку, чтоб узнать статус бага, придётся ещё и оригинал открыть, если он попал на дубликат.

Так что, я, как минимум, вреда он этой метки на дубликате не вижу.